# Install and run slimer js

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, slimerjs

Can anyone please give DETAILED explanation of how to install and run slimerjs and phantom js where slimer should pop up with a window for it to prove its running state but where as before that we should include the javascript code (.js) of any web page's.Please explain in detail how should I get the slimerjs running. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe everything you need is documented in the documentation: http://docs.slimerjs.org/current/installation.html Did you have a problem getting it to run? If so, then you should describe your problem ([edit] your question). We're not here to replicate the existing documentation of the different projects.

Comment: thanks. bt i have a doubt- the js code of a web page we provide while starting the slimer..what form it should be? pure javascript code or javascript embedded in html tags ?

Comment: Yes, you would write automation scripts in pure JavaScript and run those scripts directly with slimer.js (for example by typing `slimerjs script.js` on the commandline).